MySQL where clause with conditions based on other columns
I apologise for the vagueness of the title, but I couldn't find a better way.
There's this MySQL table which consists of entity config mapping in a flattened structure.
CREATE TABLE `entity_config` (
  `id` int unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `entity_id` bigint NOT NULL,
  `config_id` bigint NOT NULL,
  `config_value` bigint NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `entityconfig_entity_id_config_id_config_value` (`entity_id`,`config_id`,`config_value`),
  KEY `idx_config_id_config_value` (`config_id`,`config_value`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=17382 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci

Apart from the id, there are 2 composite indexes on (entity_id, config_id, config_value) and (config_id, config_value).
We have to support filter/search queries based on both config_id and config_value in the following way

Find all entity_ids that have config_id=10 and config_value=1000 and also config_id=20 and config_value=5000

The simplest way to do this is via joins
select ec1.entity_id 
from entity_config ec1 
inner join entity_config ec2 on ec1.entity_id = entity_id 
where ec1.config_id=10 
and ec1.config_value=1000 
and ec2.config_id=20 
and ec2.config_value=5000

1 join is fine but the more configs the customer wants to search, we'll have to keep adding joins and it can come to a point where we're joining the table with itself 10 times just because of 10 filters by the customer.
I tried to use case when then inside the where clause like so
select entity_id from entity_config
where (
   case when config_id=10 then config_value = 1000 when config_id=20 then config_value=5000 end
)

But this is just an OR condition which gives entity_ids that have EITHER the 1st config combo or the 2nd one.
Does anyone know any better or more efficient way of solving this? Thank you!


entity_id, config_id, config_value
"Entity", "Attribute", "Value"

This well-known pattern (and I'm not going to call it an anti-pattern right out of the gate) is, all too often, a cause of performance problems.  It has been discussed many, many times, e.g.
https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/93124/eav-is-it-really-bad-in-all-scenarios
https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/315857/entity-framework-code-first-c-class-separation-and-eav
https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/search?q=entity+attribute+value
Since you're using MySQL, you [still] have that hard limit of 61 tables per query (including any "hidden" in Views), so a very large, complex User query might actually "break" your database and if (when?) that happens, there is nothing you can do about it!
Your Relational Database would much rather work with the original entities (tables).
Do you happen to have them "lying around", nearby?

The problem is that the original entities are in a different microservice (database). The API that we have written is in another microservice. Now, your question might be why can't we write the API in that 1st microservice with the original entities? Well... that's because the 2nd microservice (along with the EAV-style entity information) also has many other metadata that we want to show. The 1st microservice doesn't even have it.
So, in short, 1 microservice has all the data but in an inefficiently stored format, and the other one has only partial data.

Something copies the data from MS1 to MS2 and into the EAV structure.  You could modify that process to take the data in a more traditional "shape" instead.
Also, having "many other metadata" in EAV form makes those "breaking and unfixable" queries all the more likely.


Find all entity_ids that have config_id=10 and config_value=1000 and
also config_id=20 and config_value=5000

The simplest way to do this is via joins
Does anyone know any better or more efficient way of solving this?


I would suggest WHERE ((config_id,config_value)) IN ((id1,val2),(idn,valn))
SELECT ec.entity_id
FROM entity_config ec 
WHERE (config_id,config_value) in ((10,1000),(20,5000))
GROUP BY entity_id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT CONCAT(config_id, '-', config_value)) = 2;

See example

I made some tests to see the difference in performance between using JOINS and WHERE (config_id,config_value) in.
MySQL version: 8.0.40-0ubuntu0.22.04.1
mysql> select count(*) from entity_config;
+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|   800040 |
+----------+

I used the following queries ,
mysql> select distinct ec1.entity_id
    -> from entity_config ec1
    -> inner join entity_config ec2 on ec2.entity_id = ec1.entity_id
    ->   inner join entity_config ec3 on ec3.entity_id = ec1.entity_id
    -> where ec1.config_id=10
    -> and ec1.config_value=1000
    -> and ec2.config_id=20
    -> and ec2.config_value=5000
    -> and ec3.config_id=1001
    -> and ec3.config_value=5001;
+-----------+
| entity_id |
+-----------+
|         1 |
+-----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
mysql>
mysql> SELECT ec.entity_id
    -> FROM entity_config ec
    -> WHERE (config_id,config_value) in ((10,1000),(20,5000),(1001,5001))
    -> GROUP BY entity_id
    -> HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT CONCAT(config_id, '-', config_value)) = 3;
+-----------+
| entity_id |
+-----------+
|         1 |
+-----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

The execution plan didn't show any big difference even if this are not proper data to test. The where in method is simpler to write and read.


Apologies. I've added the SHOW CREATE TABLE output. Also, your query doesn't seem to work in my case. It seems to do an OR operation and returns records that match either of those conditions. But I want records that match both those conditions. entity_id is not unique - it can be present with multiple config values

@SidharthSamant apologies, I have misunderstood the question. I edited and proposed another solution

COUNT(DISTINCT CONCAT(config_id, '-', config_value)) must be replaced with COUNT(DISTINCT config_id, config_value)

@Akina I can but it was slower on my tests. HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT CONCAT(config_id, '-', config_value)) = 3; was executed 0.00 sec ,in the execution plan , rows = 5 , while COUNT(DISTINCT config_id, config_value) for the same data, 1 row in set (1.54 sec) , rows 797380 and Using index for group-by (scanning) in the extra field

@ErgestBasha Does IGNORE INDEX helps?

@Akina strangely it does. Without the ignore part the optimizer choose entityconfig_entity_id_config_id_config_value index , with the ignore index it choose idx_config_id_config_value index. Now has the same execution time as the COUNT(DISTINCT CONCAT(.... I am failing to understand why. I am not a fan of using USE/FORCE INDEX or IGNORE INDEX

Not an answer. In addition to Ergest Basha's answer.
The pattern may be the next:
SELECT ec.entity_id
FROM entity_config ec 
NATURAL JOIN (SELECT 10, 1000 UNION ALL
              SELECT 20, 5000
              -- UNION ALL another values pairs
              ) AS criteria (config_id,config_value)
GROUP BY ec.entity_id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT ec.config_id, ec.config_value) = 2; -- amount of distinct pairs

This form is effective when the amount of criteria pairs is not low (~10 pairs or more). Also these values pairs may be provided as one serialized value (for example, as JSON) and parsed in the subquery (for example, using JSON_TABLE() function) which allows to count the amount of pairs dynamically in addition.
